# Using sed to append string with remote ssh not working expected

Tags: linux, ssh, sed

I want to append some text to remote file, but below commands can execute successfully locally, but failed with ssh.

**command1, failed:**

```
for i in $(cat serverlist.txt);do ssh user@$i sed -i "$a  a"  /tmp/test.txt;done
sed: -e expression #1, char 3: expected \ after `a', `c' or `i'
sed: -e expression #1, char 3: expected \ after `a', `c' or `i'
sed: -e expression #1, char 3: expected \ after `a', `c' or `i'
```

**command2 succeed:**

```
for i in $(cat serverlist.txt);do ssh user@$i sed -i "$a  t"  /tmp/test.txt;done
```

**command3 failed:**

```
for i in $(cat serverlist.txt);do ssh -T user@$i  sed -i  '$a vm.max_map_count=655360\nfs.aio-max-nr=1048576'  /tmp/test.txt;done
sed: -e expression #1, char 45: expected newer version of sed
sed: -e expression #1, char 45: expected newer version of sed
sed: -e expression #1, char 45: expected newer version of sed
```

**command4 succeed:**

```
echo " sed -i  '$a vm.max_map_count=655360\nfs.aio-max-nr=1048576'  /tmp/test.txt" >sed.cmd
for i in $(cat serverlist.txt);do ssh -T user@$i  $(cat sed.cmd)  /tmp/test.txt;done
```

Many thanks!

Comment: Where do you set the variable `$a`?

Comment: @Barmar `$a` is a `sed` command to add a line after the end of line. The examples are botched, though; several of them cannot do what the OP says they do.

Comment: Trying to do complex commands with `ssh` is always difficult, all the nested quoting and escaping will drive you crazy. The best approach is to put what you want in a script on the remote host, and then execute the script via `ssh`.

Comment: Hmmm, if your local shell is not `sh`-compatible, I guess that could explain how you see things which "aren't possible" under Bourne shell or Bash. Are you using Zsh perhaps? Configured how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to escape or quote the strings from both the local and the remote shell.

Tangentially, also, [don't read lines with `for`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor).

```sh
while IFS='' read -r host; do
    ssh user@"$host" "sed -i '\$a vm.max_map_count=655360\\nfs.aio-max-nr=1048576' /tmp/test.txt"
done <serverlist.txt
```

Notice the double quotes around the remote command, and the backslash escapes to quote the dollar sign and the literal backslash inside the double quotes.